# Laravel Dingo API returns 404 error on Apache VHosts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, dingo-api

I've build a Laravel Rest API with `Dingo\API` following a tutorial. I've set this up as virtual host at `http://site.test`

Vhosts are set up in `httpd.conf` and `/etc/hosts` files.

But, when I go to `http://site.test`, it shows the full project directory. So I have to click into the `/routes/api.php`, but I get the following error:-

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function app() in /Users/param/Desktop/api/routes/api.php
>   undefined function app() in /Users/param/Desktop/api/routes/api.php

I ran this during set up:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

My **composer.json** file

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "dingo/api": "^2.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
}
```

**RouteServiceProvider.php** file

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

**routes/api.php** file

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->get('/',  function () {
        return ['fruits'=> 'Delicious'];
    });
});
```

**.env** file

```
API_PREFIX=api
API_DEBUG=true
```

Would love any help in the right direction -- I can't figure out why `http://site.test/api` return that error?

Comment: Can you access the app at `http://site.test/public`?

Comment: Your app is served through `index.php` which is present inside the public folder, you'll need to append public in your urls,
for example  `http://site.test/public/api/`

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for a solution to this assuming your Virtual host is http://site.test
On your.env file put http://site.test as your API_URL environment variable and put site.test as your API_DOMAIN environment variable